# How to empty the array push after pushing all in the array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have problem regarding the push array, How can i empty the array for the second insertion in database. So the scenario happen in my problem is

The first insertion, is okay, If I press the submit again, the logs show multiple insert before of the push data in the array, so is it possible to empty the array after I submit again?

The first insert is equivalent of **2 items.**

So when I insert again in same order

[image: Output Second Insert]

I have variable

```
var orderNumber;
var orders = [];
var menu;
```

I have here the function of insertion.

```
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {

    $('#add_to_cart').on('click', function() {

    var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

    swal({
    title: "Are you sure to submit this?",
    text: "Once inserted, you will not be able to edit the transaction!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willInsert) => {


      if (willInsert) {

        $('.tbody_noun_chaining_order').children('tr').each(function() {
          $row = $(this);
          if ($row.hasClass('condimentParent')) {

            // store a previous menu to the orders array if exists.
            if (menu !== undefined) {
              orders.push(menu);
            }
            menu = {
              'total': $row.find('.total').text(),
              'name': $row.find('.parent_item').text(),
              'customer_id': customer_id,
              'condiments': {
                'Item': [],
                'Qty': [],
                'Total': []
              }
            };

          } else if ($row.hasClass('editCondiments')) {
            // row is a condiment, append elements to the previous "menu" variable
            menu.condiments.Item.push($row.find('.child_item').text());
            menu.condiments.Qty.push($row.find('.condiments_order_quantity').text());
            menu.condiments.Total.push($row.find('.total').text());
          }
        });
        if (menu) {
          orders.push(menu);
        }


        storeOrder(orders);



        $('table#noun_chaining_order').find('.tbody_noun_chaining_order').empty();
        $('.append_customer_noun_order_price').text('0.00');
        $('.total_amount').text('0.00');
        $('.total_amount').text('0.00');
        $('.rate_computation').text('0.00');



      } else {
        swal("Cancelled");
      }
    });

  });

});





function storeOrder(data) {

  var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();
  var place_customer = $('#place_customer').text();

  $id = "";
  $total_amount  = $('.total_amount').text();
  $append_customer_noun_order_price = $('.append_customer_noun_order_price').text();
  $tax_rate = $('.rate_computation').text();
  $delivery_rate = $('.del_rate').text();

  $.ajax({
    url:'/insert_customer_order_properties',
    type:'POST',
    data:{
      'hidden_customer_id': customer_id,
      'hidden_customer_address': place_customer,
    },
    success:function(data) {

      $id = data[0].id;

      $.ajax({
        url:'/insert_customer_payment_details',
        type:'POST',  
        data:{
          'hidden_customer_id': customer_id,
          'total_amount': $total_amount,
          'customer_sub_total': $append_customer_noun_order_price,
          'tax_rate': $tax_rate,
          'id_last_inserted': $id
        },
        success:function(data) {

           console.log(orders);

        }
      })
    }
  })


  for (var num in orders) {

    console.log(orders);

    // simulate storing the order
    $.ajax('/insert_wish_list_menu_order', {

      type: 'POST',
      // as the call is asynchronous, make sure to provide all required reference data along with the call.
      context: orders[num].condiments,

      data: {
        // 'json': '{"orderNumber":' + (orderNumber++) + '}',
        'append_customer_noun_order_price': orders[num].total,
        'append_customer_noun_order': orders[num].name,
        'customer_id': customer_id
      },
      success: function(orderNumber) {

        $order_number = orderNumber[0].id; // meron na tayong kuha ng main item..

        $.ajax({
          url:'/insert_customer_order_details_properties',
          type:'POST',
          data:{
            'order_number': $order_number,
            'data_attribute_wish_order_id': $id,
          },
          success:function(data) {
              console.log(data);

          }
        })

        if (orderNumber !== undefined) {

          $.ajax('/insert_wish_list_menu_belong_condiments', {
            context: orderNumber,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              'ParentId': orderNumber,
              'Item': this.Item,
              'Qty': this.Qty,
              'Total': this.Total
              // 'json': '{"condimentsCount": ' + this.Item.length + '}'
            },
            success: function(result) {
              //$('#result').append('Stored ' + result.condimentsCount + ' condiments for order ' + this + '<br />');
              console.log(result);
               swal("Add to cart success,Redirect to proccessing page.", {
                  icon: "success",
                });


            },

          })

        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the chat the resetting of the `orders` and `menu` variables are currently missing from your code.

This would be the bit of code you will need, insert it behind the `if (willInsert) {` condition:

```
var orders= [];
var menu= undefined;
```

And inside your `for` loop:

```
// store a previous menu to the orders array if exists.
if (menu) {
    orders.push(menu);
}
```

Comment: but after I add those two, the  function of storeOrder(orders); is not working.

Comment: @DevGe let's continue this in our chat session, will be available again in about an hour.

Comment: @Sashcha, it console log it will works, yah your work well work. the only problem is the insertion not working..

Comment: @DevGe great! So what caused the problem? Could you either add it as an answer to your own question or if my answer helped mark it as helpful/solution? P.S. If you want a user to be notified, you need to write the username exactly as is shown.